# Why does ls show wrong permissions for the group when using ACL?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, ls, acl

I have the following script for setting permissions for the Joomla CMS directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
  echo "Error: Folder does not exist or no folder given."
  echo ""
  exit 1
fi
# XAMPP uses daemon as default www-group for Apache.
WWWGROUP="daemon"
THEUSER=`who | awk '{print $1}'`
JOOMLADIR="$1"
chown -R $THEUSER:$WWWGROUP "$JOOMLADIR"
chmod g+s "$JOOMLADIR"
find "$JOOMLADIR" -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
find "$JOOMLADIR" -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;

setfacl -b -k "$JOOMLADIR"
setfacl -Rm u:$THEUSER:rwX "$JOOMLADIR"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rX "$JOOMLADIR"
setfacl -Rm d:u:$THEUSER:rwX "$JOOMLADIR"
setfacl -Rm d:g:$WWWGROUP:rX "$JOOMLADIR"

setfacl -m m::rwx "$JOOMLADIR"

# Some folders need to be writable by the web server.
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/administrator/components"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/administrator/language"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/administrator/manifests"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/administrator/modules"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/administrator/templates"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/components"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/images"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/language"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/libraries"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/media"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/modules"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/plugins"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/templates"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/cache"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/administrator/cache"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/administrator/logs"
setfacl -Rm g:$WWWGROUP:rwX "$JOOMLADIR/tmp"
# Some extra security for configuration.php:
setfacl -m g:$WWWGROUP:r "$JOOMLADIR/configuration.php"
setfacl -m o:0000 "$JOOMLADIR/configuration.php"
```

If I then use that script to set permissions for the folder of which I have a listing below, why does **every** folder then get write permission for the `daemon` group? At least, it is listed as such, though the `getfacl` command does list permissions properly.

```
totaal 172
drwxrwxr-x+ 11 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 administrator
drwxrwxr-x+  2 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 bin
drwxrwxr-x+  2 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 cache
drwxrwxr-x+  2 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 cli
drwxrwxr-x+ 19 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 components
-rw-rw-r--+  1 myuser daemon  3005 okt  4 07:52 htaccess.txt
drwxrwxr-x+  5 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 images
drwxrwxr-x+  2 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 includes
-rw-rw-r--+  1 myuser daemon  1420 okt  4 07:52 index.php
drwxrwxr-x+ 14 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 installation
drwxrwxr-x+  4 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 language
drwxrwxr-x+  5 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 layouts
drwxrwxr-x+ 12 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 libraries
-rw-rw-r--+  1 myuser daemon 18092 okt  4 07:52 LICENSE.txt
drwxrwxr-x+ 27 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 media
drwxrwxr-x+ 27 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 modules
drwxrwxr-x+ 17 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 plugins
-rw-rw-r--+  1 myuser daemon  4872 okt  4 07:52 README.txt
-rw-rw-r--+  1 myuser daemon   836 okt  4 07:52 robots.txt.dist
drwxrwxr-x+  5 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 templates
drwxrwxr-x+  2 myuser daemon  4096 okt  4 07:52 tmp
-rw-rw-r--+  1 myuser daemon  1690 okt  4 07:52 web.config.txt
```

What I am trying to achieve is this actually:

I am trying to setup an environment to develop Joomla extensions.

I'm using the Eclipse IDE with two open projects in my workspace:

- The project which contains my extension.
- The project which contains the Joomla CMS installation directory.

I'm also using the Phing build tool to copy files from the extension to the Joomla CMS installation directory to test code changes.

I'm also using XAMPP which bundles the Apache web server (which runs as user `daemon` and under group `daemon`) and serves files from `/opt/lampp/htdocs`.

Inside `/opt/lampp/htdocs` resides the Joomla installation directory at `/opt/lampp/htdocs/joomla`.

Problem is when deleting and copying the files and directories from the extension to the Joomla installation directory I get permission errors.

Why do I get permission errors? Well, that's because when I first **do** install my ZIP (extension/component) via the Joomla website (later on I want to be able to instantly see code changes by copying it directly from extension project to Joomla install directory) the webserver (Apache) creates the component as owner `daemon` and group `daemon`.

However, I want to give read, write and execute permissions for my own user (`myuser`) instead of `daemon` because I want to be able to delete the old set of files and directories from `administrator/components/com_mycomp` and `components/com_mycomp` (just an example).

I'm trying to follow a Joomla article here which tries and setup a development environment for extensions:
https://docs.joomla.org/Extension_development_using_eclipse_and_phing

Basically I just download the Joomla ZIP file, unzip it and copy it to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/joomla`.

Then I run:

`sudo securepermissions.sh /opt/lampp/htdocs/joomla`

Then it does not output any errors except for the non-existing Joomla configuration file, which it tries to set permissions to (currently tried reinstalling, that's why there is no `configuration.php` yet).

So, I run `ls -l` inside the `joomla` folder and get my listing which of course shows the mask, as user @dessert explained (and which I did not know first).

But still, when I use `find . -ls` on the `joomla` folder it still shows the permissions for group `daemon` being `rw-` for files and `rwx` for directories, even though they haven't been set this way using the script, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ACL is present, `ls -l` signals that with a `+` at the end of the permission column. Additionally it **doesn't show the group permissions but the mask instead**, see this example:

```
$ getfacl file
user::rw-
user:user:---
group::---
group:group:---
mask::rwx
other::---

$ ls -l file
-rw-rwx---+ 1 user group 0 2010-01-01 00:00 file
```

<sub>Source: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/ACL/</sub>

Besides your script can be largely simplified, see [this pastie](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25737004/), tested with [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: Just the bit in bold, that should be stapled to the internet for anyone wondering - in fact, would've been nice if `ls` would explain that in some way.