# Directory permissions - can't enter owned directory on 775 permission

Tags: directory

I've got "X" directory, setup like that

```
drwxrwxr-x+  2 git      git      4096 Aug 19 13:37 .
drwxrwx---  15 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 19 13:37 ..
```

and user called "git" can't enter the "X" directory.

What am I missing here?

"git" user is in "git" and "www-data" groups.

Comment: The `+` indicates ACLs. Use `getfacl` to get the full set of permissions on the directory. Also use `namei -lx` to check permissions on the whole path.

Comment: ... see also [Why does ls show wrong permissions for the group when using ACL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964783/why-does-ls-show-wrong-permissions-for-the-group-when-using-acl)